# What's difference between Apache Mesos, Mesosphere and DCOS?

Tags: linux, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

Looks to me that Apache Mesos is a distributed systems kernel, and Mesosphere is something Linux distribution based on Apache Mesos.

For example, its like Linux Kernel(Apache Mesos) and Ubuntu(Mesosphere).

Am I right about this?

and DCOS is a free edition of Mesosphere, like RedHat vs RedHat Enterprise?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let me try ;-)

**Apache Mesos** - OpenSource Cluster Resource Manager, Kernel of DC/OS

**Mesosphere** - Company contributing to both Apache Mesos and DC/OS

**DC/OS** - OpenSource Distribution around Apache Mesos including UI, networking, and many other pieces. Mesosphere also offers an Enterprise Edition of DC/OS with support and some advanced features.

Hope this helped!

Comment: address marathon as well

Answer (score 2):

my two cents and from various online sources...

**DC/OS** is a datacenter operating system, also a distributed system.  The operating system is based on the Apache Mesos distributed kernel. See Apache Mesos more details below

It comprises of three main components:

1. A cluster manager,
2. A container platform, and
3. An operating system.

Essentially DC/OS abstracts the infrastructure below with the Mesos and provides powerful tools that can run services and applications and more importantly you would find complete SMACK stack all pulled in under one OS platform.  DC/OS has a built-in self-healing distributed system.

It is agnostic to infrastructure layer meaning the host may consist of either virtual or physical hardware as long as it provides computing, storage and networking., it is designed to run anywhere on-premises and/or virtual AWS, AZURE….see https://dcos.io/docs/1.10/overview/

**Apache Mesos** is a distributed kernel and it is the backbone of DC/OS. It’s programmed against your datacentre as being a single pool of resources. It abstracts CPU, memory, storage and other computing resouces.. It also provides an API for resource management , scheduling across datacentre and cloud environment. It can be scale up to 10,000’s of nodes. So it can definitely be considered as a solution for large production clusters. It supports container orchestration platforms like Kubernetes and of course Marathon.

**Mesosphere** - DC/OS is created and maintained by Mesosphere

Answer (score 1):

js84 provides an excellent and concise answer above. Just to drive home the point, here is 
an analogy to the Linux ecosystem:

1. Mesos is akin to Linux kernel (as identified by Linux kernel version such as 2.6, found by command $ uname -a)
2. DC/OS is akin to Linux Operating Systems (as identified by Linux Distribution/Releases in file such as /etc/redhat-release: RHEL 7.1, CentOS 7.2), with a whole bunch of bin and utilities in /bin, /usr/bin, ...
3. Mesosphere is akin to RedHat, the company which contributes a lot to the open source Linux kernel and Linux Distribution, as well as provides paid-support to enterprise customers and additional features required by enterprise.

This is a good overview of what DC/OS is:
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/overview/what-is-dcos/

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Mesos** is the Opensource distributed orchestrator for Container as well as non-Container workloads.It is a cluster manager that simplifies the complexity of running applications on a shared pool of servers and responsible on sharing resources across application framework by using scheduler and executor.

**DC/OS(Datacenter Operating System)** are built on top of Apache Mesos. Opensource DC/OS adds  Service discovery, Universe package for different frameworks, CLI and GUI support for management and Volume support for persistent storage. DC/OS used unified API to manage multiple system on cloud or on-premises such as deploys containers, distributed services etc. Unlike traditional operating systems, DC/OS spans multiple machines within a network, aggregating their resources to maximize utilization by distributed applications.

**Mesosphere** company has products that are built on top of Apache Mesos. Mesosphere contribute to both Apache Mesos and Opensource DC/OS. Mesosphere offers a layer of software that organizes your machines, VMs, and cloud instances and lets applications draw from a single pool of intelligently- and dynamically-allocated resources, increasing efficiency and reducing operational complexity

Answer (score -2):

I understood this way, I might wrong.

DC/OS will give more features like @js84 said and Mesos will give less of DC/OS.

[image]

Apologies for bad writing on board or diagram

Comment: Can you some one explain me whats the wrong int that

Comment: Look at the the answer above

Comment: Your diagram has a bunch of abbreviations and doesn't really make a lot of sense.